# iOS 6 local notifications fail when the phone is locked with app open

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, notifications, ios6

I have an app with basic alarm functionality.  In my applicationWillResignActive: method I have it setup to create notifications to set off the alarm.  This works pretty great, and I believe this is the proper way to do it (let me know if you think there is a better way).

Only in the specific situation, ONLY ON iOS 6, when the application is not "quit" (the home button is never pressed) but the user merely locks the phone or the phone auto locks, the notifications don't go off.

I have traced through the code, and the notifications are indeed being created and it worked perfectly in iOS 5.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;

    [alarm setupForBackground];
    if ([alarm isRunning]) {
        [alarm stop];
    }
}
```

Here is the notification creation method:

```
- (void)setupForBackground
{
    UILocalNotification* alarmNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (alarmNotification) {
        alarmNotification.fireDate = alarmDate;
        alarmNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        alarmNotification.repeatInterval = 0;
        alarmNotification.soundName = @"NotificationSound.aif";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:alarmNotification];
    }
}
```

I have been searching for an answer for a while, and I could not find anything stating something about notification changes.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a semi-solution.  Apparently if you add an AlertBody to the notification, then it works.

My belief is that this is a bug in iOS 6.  As I mentioned it worked in iOS 5, the documentation makes no mention of having such a requirement, and the notification does work without the AlertBody if the application is quit (the home button is pressed).

Still curious to see if my understanding is correct and if I should file a bug report with Apple.

Thoughts anybody?

Comment: Since the functionality is different between closing the app vs. locking the phone with the app open, I've deemed it a bug and submitted a bug report to Apple.

Comment: I'm marking this as the solution as I have not found any others and Apple has yet to respond to the bug report.

Comment: Since the app is still active, I'm thinking that it is firing but instead of seeing something popup on the screen, your AppDelegate is receiving the `didReceiveLocalNotification` call.  Try implementing something in that method of your AppDelegate.